# php for keypad password with images

Tags: php, html

im trying to use a mix of html and php to allow a webpage to have a keypad like what you find on card readers and security locks. this will redirect to the html page for people to access the page inside. i am using html redirects at the moment so

```
<a href="file location on server">
<img src="keypad1" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
</a>
```

there has to be a way that i can use php to listen for the click of a button and then wait for the next one without saying correct or wrong code until the # key is pressed. after each key is pressed at this moment intime the code redirects to another page and waits for the next key. if its wrong it loads the same page until the # is pressed which is just programmed to return to another page saying error. and starts the password process again. i dont want people to just hit f12 and find out the code thats why im thinking of php if the code could be external from the websites html code. no one will have the intelligence to work out where the code is if its not in front of them. any suggestions on ways?

Comment: Everytime you click on a button and expect it to do something, then php has to refresh the page. So, I don't think that is ideal solution for you. Instead, try to play with js

Comment: ok. could you point me in a general direction.

Comment: This is very basic stuff, I am sure you can learn basics of javascript and create one in no time. What is the concept you are working on

Comment: the concept is a security webpage. certain staff cant have full access to the dvr and access control systems. but need to be able to view whats happening with them. for instance if they wanted to see who went into a certain room them can. unfortunately the software we have wont let us allow certain user to do certain things down to the leave we want. and the dvr is in a lock server cabinet under my desk to prevent tampering so once again we need remote view ect. the keypad is for the wall mounted tablets. for easier viewing and access and wall mounted pcs. need quick access for staff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PHP is a scripting language and executes at server side only.** The result you are getting on your browser is mixer of HTML, CSS and JavaScript based on what you have used with that page.

**PHP will never know what is happening on browser unless and until you inform server every time anything happens on browser.** For example clicks, mouse movement, focus, blur, keypress, keyup, all these are events that can be tracked using JavaScript.

As you are trying to develop security program that should looks like card readers keypad(http://www.govgroup.com/images_products/2407014_big.jpg), right? You can track every button press with JavaScript unless # button pressed. You can use jQuery for quick & easy implementation.

You can store every button click in JavaScript variable and when # key pressed you can send entire code to php for validation and if code is correct you can redirect to success page or else if code failed you can show the same keypad log in page again with error message.

Please check below example for how to listen to button clicks and how to store values. This is just an example, you can extend the logic to your need.

```
var buttons_pressed="";

jQuery('ul li').click(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).text() === '#'){
        alert(buttons_pressed);
        buttons_pressed="";
    }else{
        buttons_pressed += jQuery(this).text();
    }
})
```

[See @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devsaurin/ov7qs1t6/1/)

Comment: OK thanks that was a huge help but the problem now is how do i use the tracking of what they are typing to compare that against a code i set. any ideas. thanks for your help

Comment: once you have inputs you can post them to php file where you have wrote  conditions to check password. The only difference is, initially you checked for single number each time user pressed a number. That was not practical. Let user add whole password first and then send those to php to check. You can use AJAX to post data or you can create form at run-time and post it to your php file to check.